# fresh install of Doom on Windows brings up a blank (white) scratch buffer and nothing more

Tags: microsoft-windows, doom

Like it says on the box - I get the "doom loaded such and such packages on startup", but I don't get the home screen, and none of the keybindings etc. Just a white scratch buffer window with the name "*scratch* - Doom Emacs".

I've installed following the steps at https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/d5hbhl/doom_emacs_on_windows/ (using chocolatey)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are you on windows 10, you might want to try Windows Subsystem for Linux instead, and install Doom Emacs natively

Comment: This sounds like an issue of a missing font or dependency. If you run `emacs --debug-unit`, it will list every loaded package and print an entire stack trace if any errors occur. See if it says that it is missing anything and if so install it.